# problem with htlatex and tex4ht.env

Tags: tex4ht

I am compiling a document using

htlatex file.tex "html,fn-in"

This has always worked in the past. Now I am getting the following "warning" after which the program hangs - although a dvi file is created the html file is not:

tex4ht.c (2012-07-25-19:36 Windows MiKTeX)
tex4ht file.tex
  -i/tex4ht/ht-fonts/
  -ewin32/tex4ht.env
--- warning --- Can't find/open file `tex4ht.env'

I am using Miktex 2.9. I can't find tex4ht.env and am not sure why or even if it should be there. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: do you have this package installed? https://miktex.org/packages/miktex-tex4ht

Comment: It should be there, and it is in my (up-to-date) miktex in `.../MiKTeX2.9/tex4ht/base/win32/tex4ht.env`. htlatex works fine.

Comment: None of the MiKTeX-specific TeX4ht files are there. How can they be added?

Comment: You can add them using MiKTeX package manager. I think you can search for all packages containing tex4ht and install all of them.

Comment: I added the files and everything works again. Thanks for your help!